# Upload file and image to php server in android

Tags: php, android, file-upload

I use the following code in java to upload image in php server over the net.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.util.Log;

public class UploadFiles {

    public void upload(String selectedPath) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "AaB03x87yxdkjnxvi7";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        String urlString = "http://android.1mohammadi.ir/nightly/upload_files.php";
        try {
            // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    selectedPath));
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", selectedPath);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and <span id="IL_AD4" class="IL_AD">write</span> it
            // into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            // close <span id="IL_AD3" class="IL_AD">streams</span>
            Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            String str;

            while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
            }
            inStream.close();

        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
    }
}
```

And in php server use this :

```
<?php
// Where the file is going to be placed
$target_path = "/uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.
Result is "uploads/filename.<span id="IL_AD5" class="IL_AD">extension</span>" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

error_log("Upload File >>" . $target_path . "\r\n", 3, "Log.log");

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) .
        " has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " . $target_path;
}
?>
```

in android code doesn't occurs any error, and in php code also. when file upload can't move file. How can i fix this problem? 
thanks.

Comment: did you check if the upload even succeeded on the php side? The `['error']` parameter in $_FILES should **ALWAYS** be checked.

Comment: @MarcB I use `error_log("Upload File >>" .basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . " \r\n", 3,
    "Log.log");` and output is: `Upload File >>uploads/ 
Upload File >> 
`

Comment: which means there's no filename provided. the `['name']` is blank.

Comment: I use this code from http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/ and problem solved

Answer (score 7):

I use this code in server :

```
<?php
$target_path = "./uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

error_log("Upload File >>" . $target_path . $_FILES['error'] . " \r\n", 3,
    "Log.log");

error_log("Upload File >>" . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . " \r\n",
    3, "Log.log");

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) .
        " has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

and use this code in android :

```
package ir.mohammadi.android.nightly.tools;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class UploadFiles {

    public void upload(String selectedPath) throws IOException {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = selectedPath;
        String urlServer = "http://android.1mohammadi.ir/nightly/upload_files.php";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    pathToOurFile));

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream
                    .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                            + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);

            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

for more information go this [link](http://1mohammadi.ir/androidos/upload-file-in-php-server-by-android/)

Comment: In this, from where it will going to take an image?

Comment: @RajBedi `selectedPath` is address of image

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem in writing to the uploads directory. Ensure that the `/uploads/` directory exists and can be written to by the web server.

You can also [use curl](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=curl+post+file) to test your server code. Once that works you can move on to making the client work.

Comment: Uploads directory is exist.

Answer (score 0):

1mohammadi.ir answered very well. I just would like to add something on his code.

To call upload function, you need to call inside another thread (not main thread).
By doing so, follow this link. [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void postFile() {
    try {

        // Url to upload file to. Mine points to my folder in xampp
        String postReceiverUrl = "http://ipv4_address/webinterface/UploadToServer.php";
        Log.v("Some message", "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);

        // new HttpClient
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // post header
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

        // Gets the image from my drawable folder and compresses it
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.goku);
        File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir().toString(), "goku.jpg");
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

        // Uri.fromFile(file);

        // File file = new
        // File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"goku.jpg");
        // file.getAbsolutePath();
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);
        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        // execute HTTP post request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (resEntity != null) {

            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
            Log.v("Some message", "Response: " + responseStr);
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: <?php
if($_FILES){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($file["tmp_name"]);
    file_put_contents ("text.jpeg", $fileContents); 
}
?> this is my php file